# SVN works with file:/// , can't access via svn:// svnserve is running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, svnserve

on Ubuntu, 
I have SVN setup. I have created a repository called 'siteinabox' and imported the files. On the same machine, I can checkout via `file://`

This command works:

```
Input: svn checkout  file:///svn/siteinabox
```

But this command doesn't work (I tried from the same machine):

```
Input:  svn checkout  svn://localhost/siteinabox  
Output: svn: URL 'svn://localhost/siteinabox' doesn't exist
```

Ultimately my aim is to access the repo from a remote machine. Currently, it gives the same error from remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: 
I previously had started `svnserve` like this:

```
svnserve -d -r /svn/project
```

However, instead of the above command the `svnserve` should be started like this

```
svnserve -d -r /svn
```